# IDE that used in developer.android.com

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

I am new in android and I follow training in developer.android.com every day.
I would like to know that what is exact IDE used in training course on site?
I have used Android Studio 0.8.14 or Eclipse 3.6.2 but no one like windows and dialog box that is shown in training.

Comment: I would assume that they use Android Studio as that is Google's IDE.

Comment: Literally which page or image are you referring to?

Comment: this link : [link] http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Comment: @nitind this link : [link] http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html
or this : [link] http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity

Comment: @zgc7009 I've tried latest Android Studio but non of dialog box or windows like as training's pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caption for Figure 1 at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html reads, "The new activity wizard in Eclipse." It's ADT.

Eclipse 3.6.2 is many years old at this point. The current version is 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Eclipse ADT in Ubuntu, but i recommend you to use Android Studio since Google is investing more in it.